# Why can't we apply the covariant derivative to normal vector fields?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, connections, submanifold

Assume we are given an embedded Riemannian submanifold $(\mathcal{M},g)\subset (\overline{\mathcal{M}},\overline{g})$, with $\overline{\mathcal{M}}$ having the Levi-Civita connection $\nabla$ compatible with its Riemannian metric $\overline{g}$. $\mathcal{M}$'s Levi-Civita connection $\nabla^\mathcal{M}$ relates to $\nabla$ via orthogonal projection. Now, usually the definition of $\nabla^\mathcal{M}$ is that it is a bilinear operator on the space of vector bundles on $\mathcal{M}$, so sections of $\mathcal{M}$'s tangent bundle $T\mathcal{M}$.

Now I wonder, why we cannot apply $\nabla^\mathcal{M}$ to sections of $\mathcal{M}$'s normal bundle $N\mathcal{M}$? In my mind, it makes sense to talk about covariant derivatives of normal vector fields $N(t)$ along curves $c:I\rightarrow \mathcal{M}$ (i.e. $\nabla^\mathcal{M}_{c'(t)} N(t)$), since the tangent space $T\overline{\mathcal{M}}\big|_\mathcal{M}$ splits as $\bigsqcup _{x\in \mathcal{M}} T_x\mathcal{M} \oplus N_x\mathcal{M}$.

Comment: Hi! You mean 'the space of vector fields on $\mathcal{M}$'.

Comment: It makes sense to differentiate a unit normal field along a curve in $M$ (this gives the _shape operator_ of a hypersurface $M$ in $\overline{M}$), but the result is not intrinsic to $(M, g)$. Is that the question...?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Yes, I think so. Thanks for the pointer!

Answer (score 3):

Actually, you can. Have a look at Proposition 4.26 in Lee's Introduction to Riemannian Manifolds.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I had a look, but didn't quite catch how that applies to the case of vector fields in $N\mathcal{M}$. Aren't $Y$ and $\tilde{Y}$ from Proposition 4.26 also sections of $T\mathcal{M}$?

Comment: If you have a section of the normal bundle of the submanifold, you can extend this to a (local) vector field in your ambient manifold. Although you can do this in many different ways, Proposition 4.26 assures you that the result is independent of the extension you use.